# How do I recursively select rows where values in one column are present in another column?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a table like below with two columns Person and Supervisor.

| Person | Supervisor |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 |

I want to select rows where the Supervisor column only has values that are also present in the Person column.

I tried to do it with a simple:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE table.Supervisor
IN (SELECT table.Person FROM table)
```

This leaves me with:

| Person | Supervisor |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 |

The row with Person = 3 and Supervisor = 4 is removed as 4 isn't a value for a person in any of the rows.

However, the resulting table is still incorrect as the two remaining values have Supervisor = 3 which is now not present in the Person column.

Is there a way to perform this task recursively in SQL and be left with the values which satisfy the condition that the values in the Supervisor column should be present in the Person column?

Comment: You've tagged two completely different RDBMS. Step 1 - know what database you're using.

Comment: Yes they are named CTE, Common Table Expression,  there are tons of tutorials online how to run a CTE, and judging from the question it should be fairly easy to find your solution by just following tutorials.

Comment: By the logic you are using, there would be no rows returned at all unless `Person` was the same as `Supervisor` for the same row. So you don't need to use recursion, just look for all rows which have the same value

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments there is no need for recursion. You can use a CTE or a temporary table but the trick is to first "remove" any rows where the supervisor is not on the Person column - you can do that as you already have or you can use a self-join and ignore NULL values

```
select a.* from person as a
left outer join person as b on a.Supervisor = b.Person
where b.Person is not null
```

Put that into a CTE so you can reference it again and use what is essentially your original query, just referencing the CTE instead of the table i.e.

```
with cte as 
(
    select a.* from person as a
    left outer join person as b on a.Supervisor = b.Person
    where b.Person is not null
)
select * from cte
where Supervisor in (select Person from cte);
```

Note that this works in both MySQL and SQL (MSSQL) - you really must take care to tag your questions correctly